# MySQL Statement Injection

Tags: php, mysql

If someone is injecting MySQL statements to my PHP-based app. I use MySQLi real escape strings, however the attacker simply injects SQL statement. Let's assume:

http://example.com/?id=1

The attack simply injects a statement:
http://example.com/?id=1 LIMIT 10

And, even after escaping the strings, the code is executed as follows.

```
SELECT * FROM ex WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Why can't you use prepared statements?

Comment: The app is quite vast and I would have to change every single line there.

Comment: Isn't there any temporary fix for it?

Comment: There are hacky solutions. You could cast it as an integer, http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php; or you could rig up some regex. The best approach would be prepared statements though.

Comment: What about some filtering class to wipe out all the statements from input?

Comment: What do you mean by `wipe out all the statements`?

Comment: Well, MySQL statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQLi real escape strings does not prevent SQL injection, It simply helps prepare query string data and escape sensitive characters. You need to use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: Is there any way to prevent this? I am not using prepared statements, any idea to fix this real fast?

Comment: @Areeb start using prepared statements. For the particular instance you describe, you know you need a number. Use `is_numeric`.